# Github Actions Terraform Init initialized empty directory

Tags: terraform, yaml, github-actions

I am new to using Github actions and coding into YAML file.

Currently, I setup Terraform Cloud - Github actions for my Datadog POC.

I arrived on the issue:

```html
terraform init
/home/runner/work/_temp/85297372-6fed-4b1d-88f8-3c6b5527569f/terraform-bin init
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!
The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.
```

and the current github actions yaml file is:

```html
I use the terraform github actions yaml file

name: 'Terraform'

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - "main"
  pull_request:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    # Install the latest version of Terraform CLI and configure the Terraform CLI configuration file with a Terraform Cloud user API token
    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}

    # Initialize a new or existing Terraform working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
    - name: Terraform Init
      run: terraform init

    # Checks that all Terraform configuration files adhere to a canonical format
    - name: Terraform Format
      run: terraform fmt -check

    # Generates an execution plan for Terraform
    - name: Terraform Plan
      run: terraform plan -input=false

      # On push to "main", build or change infrastructure according to Terraform configuration files
      # Note: It is recommended to set up a required "strict" status check in your repository for "Terraform Cloud". See the documentation on "strict" required status checks for more information: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/types-of-required-status-checks
    - name: Terraform Apply
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/"main"' && github.event_name == 'push'
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false
```

What remedy should I do here?

I was trying to change the directory included in the terraform init to

run:
working-directory: ./DataDog-Demo/terraform
but I received also error.

Thank you

Comment: Is the terraform code in the root of the repository or there is a sub directory?

Comment: The terraform code is in different folder structure where .github workflows and terraform are same hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

You will have to `cd` into the directory which has all the terraform files. Something like this

```
- name: Build Docker image
    run: |
      cd dir
```

Alternatively, you can also set working directory like this

```
   steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Setup and run tests
        working-directory: ./app
        run: |
          cp .env .env
```

OR

```
jobs:
  unit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./app
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Do stuff
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

Comment: How can I cd with GitHub actions yml file?

Comment: Using something like this
- name: Build Docker image
    run: |
      cd ./app/dir

Comment: Updated the answer with 2 options `cd` OR `working-directory`